# How to find highest ,second highest number, Lowest Second Lowest number in given Array

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

Can anyone Please tell me how to  How to find highest ,second highest number, Lowest Second Lowest number in given Array

```
var numbers = new[] {855,3,64,6,24,75,3,6,24,45};
```

Any pointer and suggestion would really helpful . Thanks

Comment: Didn't your teacher give you directions? (If it's **homework**, please use that tag)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also try this -

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class secondHighestLowest : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    int[] arr = new int[10] { 45, 3, 64, 6, 24, 75, 3, 6, 24, 45 };

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        secondHighestLowestNumber();
        secoundLowestNumber();
    }

    private void secondHighestLowestNumber()
    {
        int firstHighestNumber = arr[0];
        int secondHighestNumber = arr[0];
        for(int i = 0; i<arr.Length; i++)
        {
            if (arr[i]>firstHighestNumber)
            {
                firstHighestNumber = arr[i];
            }
        }

        for (int x = 0; x < arr.Length; x++)
        {
            if (arr[x]>secondHighestNumber && firstHighestNumber!=arr[x])
            {
                secondHighestNumber = arr[x];
            }
        }

        Response.Write("secondHighestNumber---- " + secondHighestNumber + "</br>");
    }

    private void secoundLowestNumber()
    {
        int firstLowestNumber = arr[0];
        int secondLowestNumber = arr[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            if (arr[i] < firstLowestNumber)
            {
                firstLowestNumber = arr[i];
            }
        }

        for (int x = 0; x < arr.Length; x++)
        {
            if (arr[x] < secondLowestNumber && firstLowestNumber != arr[x])
            {
                secondLowestNumber = arr[x];
            }
        }

        Response.Write("secondLowestNumber---- " + secondLowestNumber + "</br>");
    }
}
```

Hope this is helpful :)

Comment: To format a code block, indent it 4 spaces, or select it and click the code button (101010) on the editor's toolbar.

Answer (score 4):

You don't specify the complexity requirement: one way is to sort the array in descending order and pick the top, second and third items.

Another is to build a Heap, and then perform remove root 3 times (with the heap being rebuilt after each remove).

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you have at least 2 items in the array you can use *`OrderBy()`* and *`ElementAt()`*:

```
var numbers = new[] { 855, 3, 64, 6, 24, 75, 3, 6, 24, 45 };
var secondLowest = numbers.OrderBy(num => num).ElementAt(1);
var secondHighest = numbers.OrderBy(num => num).Reverse().ElementAt(1);
```

Getting the highest and lowest is simpler and can be done using *`Max()`* and *`Min()`* LINQ methods.

```
var lowest = numbers.Min();
var highest = numbers.Max();
```

If you're worried about complexity, you can achieve better result using **[Selection algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm)**. Using it you can perform the operations in ***O(n)*** complexity.

Comment: This, IMHO, is a shocking way to do this. Hence the downvote. (providing explanation, not argument).

Comment: @silky: why is this so shocking?? Can you elaborate?? Using LINQ on a small collection like this sounds like a very natural and very obvious choice....

Comment: Creating a method that returns the highest value from an array of integers has actually been an interview question before. Max() actually turned out how to be the easiest solution.

Answer (score 4):

Using Linq Concepts

```
var a = new int[] { 855, 3, 64, 6, 24, 75, 3, 6, 24, 45 };

var Max = a.Max(z => z);
var Min = a.Min( z => z);
var SMax = a.OrderByDescending(z=>z).Skip(1).First();
var SMin = a.OrderBy(z => z).Skip(1).First();
```

Comment: SMax and SMin is only applicable if the array has no duplicate record. SMin still will return 3 as the answer which should be 6.

Answer (score 0):

```
        int[] i = new int[] { 4, 8, 1, 9, 2, 7, 3 };
        Array.Sort(i);
        Console.WriteLine("Highest number :" + i[i.Length-1]);
        Console.WriteLine("Second highest number :"+i[i.Length-2]);
        Console.WriteLine("Lowest number :" + i[i.Length-i.Length]);
        Console.WriteLine("Second Lowest number :" + i[i.Length -i.Length+1]);

        Output : Highest number : 9

                 Second highest number : 8

                 Lowest number : 1

                 Second Lowest number : 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Why two loops when can be done in

```
        int[] myArray = new int[] { 2, 4, 3, 6, 9 };

        int max1 = 0;
        int max2 = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < myArray.Length; i++)
        {
            if (myArray[i] > max1)
            {
                max2 = max1;
                max1 = myArray[i];

            }
            else
            {
                max2 = myArray[i];
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("first" + max1.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("Second" + max2.ToString());
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: does not work in case of int[] myArray = new int[] { 9, 4, 3, 6, 2 };

Answer (score 0):

I have first arranged them using Selection Sort algorithm in ascending order, then i displayed values.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] Num =new int[] { 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0,99,105,55 };

        int temp;
        for(int a=0;a<Num.Length-1;a++)
        {
            for(int b=a+1;b<Num.Length;b++)
            {
                if(Num[a]>Num[b])
                {
                    temp = Num[a];
                    Num[a] = Num[b];
                    Num[b] = temp;
                }
            }

        }


        Console.WriteLine("Max value ="+Num[Num.Length-1]+"\nSecond largest Max value="+ Num[Num.Length - 2]+"\nMin value =" + Num[0] + "\nSecond smallest Min value=" + Num[1]);
        Console.WriteLine("\nPress to close");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This algorithm is applicable even with duplicate record.

```
int[] intArrayInput= new int[] { 855, 3, 64, 6, 24, 75, 3, 6, 24, 45, 855 };
```

Using Sort:

```
Array.Sort(intArrayInput);
int intMax = intArrayInput[intInput.Length - 1];
int intLow = intArrayInput[0];
```

And using LINQ:

```
int intSecondMax = intArrayInput.OrderByDescending(x => x).Distinct().Skip(1).First();
int intSecondLow = intArrayInput.OrderBy(x => x).Distinct().Skip(1).First();
```

Answer (score 0):

## Here is an easy solution assuming you array has at least two members.

### For the lowest number in the array.

```html
              
 Array.Sort(new);

            string newNumber = string.Join(" ", new[0]);
            return newNumber;
```

### For second lowest number in the array.

```html
                Array.Sort(new);
                string newNumber = string.Join(" ", new[1]);
                return newNumber;
```

### for the highest number in the array.

```html
                    Array.Sort(new);
                    string newNumber = string.Join(" ", new[new.Length - 1]);
                    return newNumber;
```

### For the second highest number in the array.

```html
                        Array.Sort(new);
                        string newNumber = string.Join(" ", new[new.Length - 1]);
                        return newNumber;
```

Answer (score 0):

Shortest way to find out largest, second largest, smallest & second smallest number, using conventional method:

```cs
int LargestNumber = 0;
int SecondLargestNumber = 0;
int SmallestNumber = 0;
int SecondSmallestNumber = 0;
int[] array = new int[] { 250, 5, 17, 50, 98, 352, 2, 8, 67, 150, 200, 1 };

for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    if (array[i] > LargestNumber)
    {
        SecondLargestNumber = LargestNumber;
        LargestNumber = array[i];
    }
    else if (array[i] > SecondLargestNumber)
    {
        SecondLargestNumber = array[i];
    }

    if (i == 0)
    {
        SmallestNumber = array[0];
        SecondSmallestNumber = array[1];
    }

    if (array[i] < SmallestNumber)
    {
        SecondSmallestNumber = SmallestNumber;
        SmallestNumber = array[i];
    }
    else if (array[i] < SecondSmallestNumber)
    {
        SecondSmallestNumber = array[i];
    }
}

Console.WriteLine("Largest Number : " + LargestNumber);
Console.WriteLine("Second Largest Number : " + SecondLargestNumber);
Console.WriteLine("Smallest Number : " + SmallestNumber);
Console.WriteLine("Second Smallest Number : " + SecondSmallestNumber);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
int[] myUnSortArray = { 1, 5, 8, 3, 10, 6, 19, 5, 4, 4 };

int[] SortedArray = (from number in myUnSortArray
                     orderby number ascending
                     select number).ToArray();

int highestValue = SortedArray.Max();
int SecondHighest = SortedArray.Last(m => m < highestValue);
```